# Plotted Value of an Oscillator became Higher relative to its Previous plotted value

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In the context of a strategy, how can one specify a buy order to be executed
when the plotted value of an oscillator, say RSI, has just increased relative to its previous plot, while still being under a specified value.

For example:
RSI
'while under 23'
28 -> 19 -> 18 -> 22 (ok go long)

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Jxo.png)

Thanks in advance.

Don't know where to go from
rsi[0] > rsi[1]

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. The following code goes off your example and plots a triangle only when RSI increases for the first time after being below 23 and is still below 23. This is done by adding a boolean.

[image]

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
rsi = ta.rsi(close,14)
var firstUp = false

hline(23, color = color.black)
goLong = firstUp == false and rsi > rsi[1] and rsi < 23

if goLong
    firstUp := true
if rsi > 23
    firstUp := false

plot(rsi)
plotshape(goLong ? rsi - 1 : na , 'go long', style = shape.triangleup, location= location.absolute, color = color.green, size = size.small)
```